# Reading the result of a contest from a file and sort the name alphabetically with related score

Tags: c, xcode

i have to read from a file which contains names and scores the results of a contest but the function fscanf is not working properly.. Does it have to do with newlines or something? 
I'll leave below the code and the screenshots of the issue i'm having.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>

   typedef struct contest
   {
      char name[25];
      int score;
   }Contest;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

Contest players[100];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("contest.txt", "r");

if(fp == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: failed to open the file\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int cnt = 0;
while(fscanf(fp, "%s  %d", players[cnt].name, &players[cnt].score) != EOF)
{
        ++cnt;
}

char temp[25];
for(int t = 0; t < cnt; ++t)
{
    for(int u = 0; u < cnt; ++u)
    {
        if(strcasecmp(players[t].name, players[u].name) > 0)
        {
            strcpy(temp, players[t].name);
            strcpy(players[t].name, players[u].name);
            strcpy(players[u].name, temp);
        }
    }
}

for(int t = 0; t < cnt; ++t)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "Name : %s  Score : %d\n", players[t].name, players[t].score);
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
Randal  34  
Leonel  67  
Vaughn  100  
Missy  68  
Cristopher  92  
Dagmar  102  
Blondell  88  
Milly  83  
Darrel  12  
Josh  71
```

Output:

[image: Running the program]

Comment: Please do not post text as picture.

Comment: @alk ok sorry i just copied it also, sorry i'm new to stack overflow

Comment: The program worked as expected for me.  You may consider posting the output of " od -Ax -tx1 contest.txt", so we can all see exactly what newline scheme the file is using.

Comment: @amasmiller ok thank you very much now it's also working to me it was only because there were 2 spaces between name and score

Comment: @amasmiller ok thank you very much now it's also working to me it was only because there were 2 spaces between name and score

Comment: Ok, I finalised your fix for input, please now do  the same for the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just made two little mistakes: (1) forgot to also swap the scores and (2) did the wrong comparison in the strcasecmp. For the rest, it's all working fine here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct contest
{
    char name[32];
    int score;
} Contest;

int main()
{
    Contest players[100];
    FILE *fp = fopen("contest.txt", "r");
    assert(fp);

    int cnt = 0;
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s  %d", players[cnt].name, &players[cnt].score) != EOF)
        ++cnt;

    for(int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cnt; ++j)
        {
            if(strcasecmp(players[i].name, players[j].name) < 0)
            {
                int tempScore = players[i].score;
                players[i].score = players[j].score;
                players[j].score = tempScore;

                char tempName[32];
                strcpy(tempName, players[i].name);
                strcpy(players[i].name, players[j].name);
                strcpy(players[j].name, tempName);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
        fprintf(stdout, "Name : %s  Score : %d\n", players[i].name, players[i].score);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```